# HTML5 Audio & Video pause function on page change

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, pause

I have several separate pages in my html. The nav home page has a youtube vid embedded. There is also a nav music page which incorporates 5 album/cds each with it's own playlist/audio player. How can I stop the video and/or audio from playing when the page changes? The nav has 6 links (home, music, about, gigs, lyrics, contact.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#home').load('home.html');
  $('#music').load('player.html');
  $('#about').load('about.html');
  $('#gigs').load('gigs.html');
  $('#contact').load('contact.html'); 
 })
 
 $('.menu a').on('click', function() {
 
$('#utube')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*'); 
});
```

```html
<nav>
   <div class="hambtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</div>
  <div id="sidenav" class="menu">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
   <a href="#home">home</a>
   <a href="#music">music</a>
   <a href="#about">about</a>
   <a href="#gigs">gigs</a>
   <a href="#contact"><span>contact</span></a>
  </div>
</nav>
<section>
 <article>
  <div id="home"></div>
  <div id="music"></div>
 </article>
</section>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>utube responsive</title>
<style type="text/css">
#utube{
 margin:0 auto;
 width:80%;
 height:auto;
}
.video-responsive{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.video-responsive iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="utube" class="video-responsive"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5Q-8kRVjAe8?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm wondering why I have no input from the community here. I have 50 views but no replies. I find it hard to believe that no one has any input???